# Menu Color Changes on mouse leave

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am working on this GUI and am running into a small issue with styling. I am trying to customize the program as much as I can but can need to get the default Menu styling to correctly change. The problem is, when I hover over the Menu, and the Menu Item's, the correct color is used. However, when I leave the button, the default blue color reappears. You can see this on the "Themes" button. If I were to hover over it, it would turn to the red color that currently illuminates the "Light" Menu Item.

[image: Weird Glitch]

```
.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 118, 118) 0%, rgb(237, 101, 101) 100%);
    -fx-text-fill: lightgrey;
}

.menu .text, .menu-item:hover .text {
    -fx-fill: white;
}

.menu-item:hover, .menu:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #ea5353;
}

.menu-item .text {
    -fx-fill: black;
}
```

I have tried other psuedo selectors such as ".menu:pressed, .menu:focused, .menu:selected" but did not have success with either of them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using

```css
.menu-bar {

    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 118, 118) 0%, rgb(237, 101, 101) 100%);    
    -fx-selection-bar: #ea5353 ;
    -fx-text-background-color: lightgrey ;
    -fx-focused-text-base-color: white ;
}
```

Here's a test harness:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MenuStyleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Menu themes = new Menu("Themes", null, new MenuItem("Light"), new MenuItem("Dark"),
                new MenuItem("Cherry Blossom"));
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(new Menu("File"), themes, new Menu("Help"));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(menuBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With `style.css` containing the CSS above, this gives

[image]

Comment: How would I find out about this property? It does appear to be here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: How would I also get the text-fill to stay?

Comment: It's not a property; it's a looked-up color. I usually just go to the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for the default style sheet to figure out how things work.

Comment: Updated with some experimentation with text fills.